# vscode can not use for native module?

Tags: java, android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I using react-native. When I implement native module, it pops up errors window all the place like "The import android cannot be resolved (Java)" when I import something like android.widget.Toast.
The code still run well but it cause very hard for me to developed. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Open a new XCode window with the directory being the android folder, using `code android` when you are inside the react native folder. I am able to get autocomplete, intellisense and autoimport in this window.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to delete the caches of the project. as it was storaged under:

"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage".

many folders under it, as a folder correspondence a project, delete the correspondence folder of this project(as you can identify it through the 'modified date').